# Push a div to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm coding a menu in french but I need to move all the buttons (Home, About us...) to the right.

I tried with `float: right;` but it doesn't work.

Here is my Result :

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhXe.png)[image]

The `<a>` Home, Informations, etc.. are in a div. It's this div that i want to push right !

My Objective :[image]

[My Objective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Ac2.png)

My Code:

```css
/*
  
            ==============================
            NAVBAR
            ==============================
  
            */

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #9ebd11/*55d6aa*/
  ;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  /*padding: 10px 0;*/
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav #navbar-ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav .navbar-li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}

nav .navbar-button {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav .navbar-button:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav .navbar-button::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav .navbar-button:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

nav #register-li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}

nav #register-button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav #login-li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}

nav #login-button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav,
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.connection {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/Logo/logo_gp_.png" width="100" alt="Description de l'image"></a>
    </h1>

    <nav>
      <ul id="navbar-ul">
        <li class="navbar-li"><a href="#" class="navbar-button">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-li"><a href="#" class="navbar-button">Informations</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-li"><a href="#" class="navbar-button">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="connection">
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" id="register-button">S'inscrire</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" id="login-button">Se connecter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks

Comment: Read up on "how to create navbars in bootstrap" the official documentation is a good start

Comment: Can you set percentage for logo and nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float won't work because your container is a flex-container.

Just use:justify-content:space-between`

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #9ebd11/*55d6aa*/
  ;
}

nav #navbar-ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav .navbar-li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}

nav .navbar-button {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav .navbar-button:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav .navbar-button::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav .navbar-button:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

nav #register-li {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: relative;
}

nav #register-button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav #login-li {
  position: relative;
}

nav #login-button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav,
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.connection {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <h1 class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/Logo/logo_gp_.png" width="100" alt="Description de l'image"></a>
    </h1>

    <nav>
      <ul id="navbar-ul">
        <li class="navbar-li"><a href="#" class="navbar-button">Home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-li"><a href="#" class="navbar-button">Informations</a></li>
        <li class="navbar-li"><a href="#" class="navbar-button">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="connection">
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" id="register-button">S'inscrire</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" id="login-button">Se connecter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's "Container" class has a max-width of something like 1800px(not certain of exact px count).

Try using "container-fluid". This should allow the nav items to move to the far right but will probably move your logo to the far left because of your .logo float-left css.

You can give the logo a margin-left that works for you.

Edit: I just noticed you've defined your own .container class in the css. And margin set to 0 auto. This is going to center your content within the container class and give you max width of 80% so your content won't reach the far right side of the browser unless you set this items to "position:absolute" and then give them the necessary margins.

Answer (score -1):

**Try changing your nav class from:**

```
nav{
  floaf: right;
}
```

**to:**

```
nav{
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

This should force your nav element to position it's right 20px left of the parent elements right. Tested in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

remove the `float: right` from your `.nav` and add `float:left` from `.logo`

Now add `display:flex` to your `.logo` and for your container add:

```
.container{
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I have not tested this. Let me know if this is what you wanted.